# Is there any airport planning to install ILS CAT IIIc?

Tags: ils

I know that right now no airport has an [ILS CAT IIIc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrument_landing_system#ILS_categories), but is there any airport in the world planning to have one in a near future?

Otherwise why bother to have rules and specifications for something not even planned to be in future?

Comment: The technology required for implementing CAT IIIc approaches does not yet exist. Specifically, taxing in 0 visibility is not possible.

Comment: Related: [Are zero visibility landings practical and desirable for commercial aviation?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12626/3201)

Comment: @J.Hougaard considering the fact that we currently have self-driving cars that have to navigate streets full of other, barely controlled moving things, applying that same technology to aircraft, which only move on the ground in very controlled situations, shouldn't be too big a stretch. I would say it is _possible_, it just hasn't been done yet.

Comment: @FreeMan We're saying the exact same thing, just using different words.

Comment: Sounds like we have the required technology (scientific knowledge and engineering experience) for it to be possible (to implement after further R&D), but not the required technology (actual software, hardware and procedures) for it to be possible (to implement without further R&D).

Answer (score 2):

Landing is one thing, taxiing with no visibility whatsoever is another.

At the moment the answer is no. But new rules are in place that *may* one day allow it (or its equivalent). See this Rockwell Collins post: [Worth the Wait — FAA’s New EFVS Rule FAR 91.176](https://blogs.rockwellcollins.com/2017/01/17/worth-the-wait-faas-new-efvs-rule-far-91-176/).

> Main benefits to FAA’s new [EFVS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_flight_vision_system) rule:
>
> - Enhances low-visibility flight and ground operations
>
> (...)
>
> - Enables descent below Decision Altitude/Decision Height (DA/DH) or Minimum Descent Altitude (MDA) in low visibilities on a greater number of approach procedure types (precision, approach procedure with vertical guidance (APV) and non-precision)

It's still a new rule and thus the implementations are not clear yet.

---

RE: Why have specs and not use them?

The CAT IIIc definition [may soon be removed](http://fsims.faa.gov/PICDetail.aspx?docId=OSWG%202017-03%20Agenda):

> [A] preview of proposed changes to the draft OpSpec and 14 CFR part 121 to date [was presented]. The definition of Cat IIIa, IIIb, and IIIc will be removed from the regulation. The FAA will continue to use the same definitions, however they will not be defined in 14 CFR. In the future, expect the NOS Charts to depict only **one minima for Cat III.**

It's unclear what that will entail. And what ICAO will do. So there's a chance the zero/zero definition will no longer be there.

---

Related: [Is it true an ILS CAT IIIc can automatically taxi-in an aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/29375/14897)

Comment: Why would taxiing (on the ground, very low speed) be _harder_ in zero visibility than flying in to land (in the air, very high speed)?

Comment: @Sean - There is no [radio] guidance for taxiing except the pilot's vision. However night vision technology is making its way into the regulations governing the landing minima if I recall correctly, still early stages.