# Do airports use automated ground operation systems?

Tags: air-traffic-control, airport-operations

I'm interested to know if any airports use an automated ground operation system guide planes between gates and vise/versa from/to landing strips/tarmacs.

Comment: I feel like there is a dupe hanging around somewhere but can't seem to find it

Comment: The last sentence of your question really turns this into a shopping question, which is explicitly off-topic here. I also do not believe that there is any automatic guidance system in use today, unless you are talking about taxiway lighting systems that help a pilot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it true an ILS CAT IIIc can automatically taxi-in an aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/29375/is-it-true-an-ils-cat-iiic-can-automatically-taxi-in-an-aircraft)

Comment: Nope, ground movements are what the railroads call ["dark territory"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_territory). *shudder*

Answer (score 2):

Advance Surface Movement Guidance & Control Systems (ASMGCS) in different levels are being used for this purpose.  Many airport in the world uses the concept of Follow Green, where the aircraft is supposed to follow the green taxiway centre line lights to reach the parking stand after vacating runway and vice versa.  Surface Movement Radars combined with MLATs aid for these purpose.

You can find more information on this from [ICAO Doc 9830](https://www.icao.int/Meetings/anconf12/Document%20Archive/9830_cons_en%5B1%5D.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing (as far as I know) thats currently in place to guide planes on the ground. [Some airports are equipped with ASDE-X systems](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/technology/asde-x/) which allow the tower to monitor ground movements closely (and potentially if they are out of sight) but the system does not offer any progressive guidance capabilities. Take a look at the question @Pondlife has linked in the comments for some more interesting info on how this has been a limiting factor in cat IIIc approaches.